# Which NotifyFilter triggered FileSystemWatcher.Changed?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

When creating a `FileSystemWatcher`, we have the option to select which `NotifyFilters` to watch for. To my understanding however, there are multiple `NotifyFilters` that could trigger the `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event, such as `NotifyFilters.LastWrite` or `NotifyFilters.Attributes`.

**Code:**

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(PATH);
watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(PATH);
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Security |
                        NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
watcher.Changed += OnFileSystemWatcher_Changed;
watcher.Deleted += OnFileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
watcher.Created += OnFileSystemWatcher_Created;
watcher.Renamed += OnFileSystemWatcher_Renamed;

private void OnFileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

**Problem:** In my event handler for the `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event, is there a way to determine which `NotifyFilter` raised the event?

**Attempt:** I was thinking about just creating a new `FileSystemWatcher` for each type of `NotifyFilter`, but that doesn't seem like a very efficient use of memory. I was hoping there'd be a cleaner method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to find this out, because underlying windows api which is called by `FileSystemWatcher` does not provide such information. Api which is called is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) and it returns result in [FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391(v=vs.85).aspx) structure with the following fields:

```
typedef struct _FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION {
  DWORD NextEntryOffset;
  DWORD Action;
  DWORD FileNameLength;
  WCHAR FileName[1];
} FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION, *PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION;
```

Where action is created\modified\deleted\renamed. As you see - no information about what filter has triggered the change.